# Euclid in Prolog (greatest common denominator)

Tags: recursion, prolog, greatest-common-divisor

We've been given a pseudo-code that we are supposed to translate into Prolog:

[image]

This is the solution I've been able to come up with:

```
% if y = 0: return x
test(X, 0, Output) :- Output is X.
% if x = 0: return y
test(0, Y, Output) :- Output is Y.
% if if x > y: return euclid_recursive(x - y, y)
test(X,Y,Output) :- 
    % if x > y: return euclid_recursive(x - y, y)
    (   X > Y ->  Temp is X - Y ,
        test(Temp, Y,Output);
    % return euclid_recursive(x, y - x) 
        Temp is Y - X,
        test(X, Temp, Output)
    ).
```

I've tested it with a few examples and it seems to work. I would appreciate it if you folks could have another look at it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use [**`is/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) to evaluate a numerical expression. So here you can use *unification*:

```
test(X, 0, X).
test(0, X, X).
test(X, Y, Output) :- 
    ( X > Y
    -> Temp is X - Y,
       test(Temp, Y,Output)
    ; Temp is Y - X,
      test(X, Temp, Output)
    ).
```

Another major problem is that Prolog will keep making recursive calls, even if one of the elements is zero. It will thus keep proposing new solutions:

```
?- test(36, 63, R).
R = 9 ;
R = 9 ;
R = 9 ;
R = 9 ;
R = 9 ;
R = 9 ;
R = 9 ;
R = 9 ;
R = 9 ;
R = 9 ;
R = 9 ;
R = 9 ;
…
```

This may not seem like a (major) problem, but if you use `test/3` as part of another program, it can get stuck in an infinite loop where `test/3` keeps proposing `R = 9`, and the next predicate call each time rejecting this.

```
test(X, 0, X).
test(0, X, X) :-
    X > 0.
test(X, Y, Output) :- 
    X > 0,
    Y > 0,
    ( X > Y
    -> Temp is X - Y,
       test(Temp, Y,Output)
    ; Temp is Y - X,
      test(X, Temp, Output)
    ).
```

This will only propose one solution:

```
?- test(36, 63, R).
R = 9 ;
false.
```